# How do I take this button out?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making this app to display lame jokes and basically the layout has a back buutton, (which the red arrow points to). But whenever I press it, the app crashes. I learned that the hardware back button (on the right side) works just fine. Since I'm on a tight deadline, I'm fine with just using the hardware button. So where would I find the code to take out the back button, or how would I take it out? Thanks so much guys!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how would I take it out?`

For disabling the back button on `Action` bar, in the `onCreate()` function of your `Activity` try:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Hope it helps.